How do you talk about p-values in Latin?
For instance, let's say you want to say this in Latin:

In social sciences, p-values lower than 5% are usually considered statistically significant.

How would you say that? My attempt would be:

In scientiis socialibus, p-valores minores quam 5% solent considerari statisticaliter significantes.

